# Can't update apps even though I have space

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-9

Can't update apps even thhough my Samsung Galaxy S9 Plus is having 10 gigabytes of free RAM. The update fails and the playstore glaims I have "no space". Any idea?

Comment: PlayStore is not complaining about your RAM (volatile memory, lost when reboot or shut down the phone)), it is complaining about missing flash memory (persistent memory, survives power off and reboot).

Answer (score 0):

Could you send a picture of the playstore result. I believe the s9plus doesn't not have 10GB ram as well. You can try to clear playstore cache or install 3rd party stores like Apkpure or uptodown to install the updates you want if you believe that playstore has problems.